# Calculating the sensor size or pixel pitch of the Logitech BRIO 4K Webcam?

Tags: resolution, sensor-size, megapixels, pixels, pixel-size

I have a [Logitech BRIO](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/brio) webcam and want to try and calculate some of its physical dimensions like the sensor size or the physical size of each pixel.

Unable to find any info on the official site, I saw a blog post that [claims](https://www.kurokesu.com/main/2017/09/18/logitech-brio-4k-webcam-rework-instructions/) that the camera has a 1/4" sensor in the comments.

What is this 1/4" referring to exactly? Can I use this number and the max resolution of the camera (4096 x 2160) to calculate the physical size of each pixel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if the 1/4" description is valid for your camera, but in general, the tiny CCD digital sensors are often described by comparing their size to the video vacuum tubes used until about 1980. It represents the outer glass tube diameter, not the actual sensor portion of it.

Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format#Table_of_sensor_formats_and_sizes  has a table that describes the 1/4" video tube size as being 3.60 x 2.70 mm, which was of course a 4:3 aspect ratio back then, not 16:9 today.  If that is valid for your camera, and if it is using 16:9, then the maximum size would be 3.60 x 2.02 mm.  Lots of "IFs" involved though.